# In production Webpack 2.2.0.rc-0 will uglify/minify vendor.js and manifest.js but not bundle.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to figure out why my vendor and manifest files are minified and uglified but my bundle is not.  Could it be the order of the plugins? Maybe something to do with the CommonsChunkPlugin?

This is my UglifyJsPlugin code:

```
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      debug: false,
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      compressor: {  // eslint-disable-line camelcase
        warnings: false,
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true
      },
      mangle: false
    }),
```

and this is my webpack config object a whole:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');
const del = require('del');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
    vendor: `./src/app/dependencies`,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.json$/,
        use: ['json-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: ['tslint-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          'ng-annotate-loader',
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['ts-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /.html$/,
        use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jade|pug)$/,
        use: ['pug-html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
        use: ['url-loader?limit=30000&name=[name]-[hash].[ext]']
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'less-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      debug: false,
      minimize: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      output: {
        comments: false
      },
      compressor: {  // eslint-disable-line camelcase
        warnings: false,
        unused: true,
        dead_code: true
      },
      mangle: false
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // emits no scripts to browser if there are any errors at all
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html'),
      inject: true
    }),

    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
      conf.paths.src
    ),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
        resolve: {},
        ts: {
          configFileName: 'tsconfig.json'
        },
        tslint: {
          configuration: require('../tslint.json')
        }
      }
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        from: path.join(conf.paths.src, 'integration', 'embedder', 'embedder.js'),
        to: path.join('integration', 'embedder', 'embedder.js')
    }])
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.webpack.js',
      '.web.js',
      '.js',
      '.ts'
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out the answer was to add an options config to the babel-loader to include presets es2015 as so:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'ng-annotate-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

This is needed for uglify/minifying es6 code with webpack 2.